# Как сделать список, раскрывающий метки на Яндекс.Карте?

Tags: карты, yandex-maps-api, javascript

Как реализовать Яндекс.Карту с несколькими метками на ней, а рядом — список этих меток, при клике на элементы которого происходит раскрытие определённой метки на карте?

Есть [пример](http://joomla.zhuk.cc/index.php/zhyandex-demo-placemarklist), но разобраться вообще никак не могу.

Answer (score 1):

Посмотрите информацию [на этой странице](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/ymapsml/1.x/examples/) и в частности пункт "Создание меню для отображения коллекций объектов". Кроме того, почитайте "[Как создать меню с помощью элемента управления](http://api.yandex.ru/maps/doc/jsapi/1.x/articles/tasks/overlays.xml)", что ближе всего к вашей поставленной задаче.